# Proper way to convert char* to NSString without initWithCString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, char

I'm pulling a listing of results from a SQLite3 database into a `UITableView`.  The code where I pull text from the database is like so:

```
char *menuNameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
NSString *menuName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:menuNameChars];
NSLog(@"Retrieved %s,%@ from DB.", menuNameChars, menuName);
```

When I use `initWithUTF8String`, sometimes the information is copied properly from the database.  Sometimes though, the information is displayed properly from the `char*`, but not from the `NSString`:

```
2011-10-24 22:26:54.325 [23974:207] Retrieved Cravin Chicken Sandwich – Crispy, (null) from DB.
2011-10-24 22:26:54.327 [23974:207] Retrieved Cravin Chicken Sandwich – Roast, (null) from DB.
2011-10-24 22:26:54.331 [23974:207] Retrieved Jr Chicken Sandwich, Jr Chicken Sandwich from DB.
2011-10-24 22:26:54.337 [23974:207] Retrieved Prime-Cut Chicken Tenders - 3 Piece, Prime-Cut Chicken Tenders - 3 Piece from DB.
```

Now, if I replace `initWithUTF8String` with `initWithCString`, the code works perfectly.  However, XCode 4.2 tells me that `initWithCString` has been deprecated.  I know enough to understand I don't want to use deprecated code, but if `initWithUTF8String` isn't working, what should I use?

Comment: Have you tried `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", menuNameChars]`?

Comment: Why don't use a wrapper around sqlite like FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb?

Comment: @Dani then why not use Core Data? Even easier.

Comment: @WTP: maybe he already has an existing mysql database?

Comment: @DanielRHicks:  I haven't tried that, but if stringWithFormat works the same as NSLog, that would definitely be a solution!

@Dani/@WTP:  I'm actually planning to use the FMDB wrapper in this program, but when I tried to add in the FMDB code, it caused a number of EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, so I put FMDB on the backburner for now.  As for Core Data, I haven't learned how to use Core Data (yet).  It's on the todo list though!

Comment: @DanielRHicks your suggestion solves the (null) problem, but the answer given below from Rob shows why it was showing (null) in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see that the dash in your first log line (`Retrieved Cravin Chicken Sandwich ...`) isn't a simple ASCII `HYPHEN-MINUS` (U+002D, UTF-8 2D).  It's a Unicode `EN DASH` character (U+2013, UTF-8 E2 80 93).  Same for the second line.  My guess is they're encoded incorrectly in your database.  If you give `-[NSString initWithUTF8String:]` a C-string that's not valid UTF-8, it returns `nil`.

Try printing a hex dump of `menuNameChars`.  You can do that by setting a breakpoint on the line after the call to `sqlite3_column_text`.  When the breakpoint is reached, right-click/control-click `menuNameChars` in your stack frame window and choose `View memory of "*menuNameChars"` (note the `*`).

Comment: Since it's printing "(null)", this would appear to be a mistake made on Stack Overflow, not the actual problem.

Comment: That's a mistake on my part -- I retyped the code instead of C&P.  It is %s,%@ in the code.

Comment: The suggestion by @DanielRHicks above fixes my problem -- but your answer gives me the cause.  I'm using Excel to sort/edit the information in my database, and when I do two hyphens, it autocorrects it to the "EN DASH" character like you said.  This is the reason why my code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear the data is not encoded as UTF-8. You should find out what encoding is being used and then use `initWithCString:encoding:` and pass the correct encoding.

Comment: If I use **initWithCString** it's properly passed to the NSString -- however **initWithCString** is deprecated.  From what I can tell in the Apple docs, **initWithUTF8String** is the function that replaced it, but it gives me the above (null) response.  Would there be a way I can find the encoding from the code?

Answer (score 2):

try the power of `stringWithFormat:`

Comment: +1 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",property_getName(property)]

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at Apple Developer it seems that instance method *initWithCString*: is only deprecated for the version without explicit **encoding:** specifier. With good reason one could argue and thus perfectly valid for const char * C-string conversion to NSString. Please compare:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497394-initwithcstring

to newer *initWithCString:encoding:*

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411950-initwithcstring?language=objc

This Foundation API change was made since macOS 10.4+.